# php include error not findind the path

Tags: php, mysql

I have this little code, which in fact is a login script which check if the register is on, and show it after the login button:

```
   <?php
include("../inc/db.php"); 
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
{
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $username = $_POST['user'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'";
    $rez = $pdo->query($sql);   
    if($rez->fetchColumn()  > 0)
    {
        ...

    }
    else {echo '<p align="center">...</p>';}
    }
    else { echo '<p align="center">...</p>'; }
    }
    ?>
    <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="login">
    <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="78">Username</td>
    <td width="6">:</td>
    <td width="294"><input name="user" type="text" id="user"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="pass" type="password" id="pass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $sql = "SELECT setare FROM setari WHERE nume_setare = 'OPEN_REG'";
    $openreg = $pdo->query($sql)->fetch();
    if($openreg['setare'] == 1)
    {
     ?>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="register">Inregistrare</a></td>
    </tr><?php } ?>
    </table>
    </td>
    </form>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

My problem is this line:

> include("../inc/db.php"); 
>    Warning: include(E:/wamp/www//inc/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\wamp\www\proiect1-test\scripts\login.php on line 3
>    Warning: include(): Failed opening '../inc/db.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in E:\wamp\www\proiect1-test\scripts\login.php on line 3

and i can't figure it out where i'm wrong. The path is correct, and if i hit the login button, it works.If i hit login button with an inccorect combination of username and password, the warning disappear. However, it doesn't include that when i open it for the first time. This login file is included in the index of the site.

Comment: If it tells you that the file couldn't be found, then the path is *not* correct. You should trust the computer on that one.

Comment: If the path would be correct PHP would not complain. Define a fixed path constant in your front-controller and reference it later on.

Comment: the fact i don't understand it that it says it is inccorect, but using the login button, i use information from that file

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path to that file is obviously incorrect. This commonly happens when you use a relative path to a file and then start placing files in different directories. You should use the full system path to the file to avoid this issue:

```
include("/path/from/root/to/inc/db.php");
```

A common thing to do is define a variable or constant that defines the root path to your web files. That way if it ever changes (i.e. you change hosts) you only need to change it in one place.

In your config file:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', '/path/from/root/to/');
```

In your PHP files;

```
include(ROOT_PATH . "inc/db.php");
```

Comment: if it would be an inccorect path, then the script wouldn't work at all. it doesn't work on first use, after hitting the login button, it works fine.

Comment: Harcoding an absolute path is pretty bad practice as well, since it makes code extremely hard to port to other systems.

Comment: @user3054345 Because you use `include()` and not `require()` your script won't fail.

Comment: @deceze You left your comment as I addressed that issue.

Comment: @user3054345 Have you tried using the full path to that file?

Comment: i tried the one with the ROOT_PATH . , but still doesn't work

Comment: Did you verify that the path is correct first? I would hard code it in *first* and then use the second option once you are sure you have the right value.

Comment: hmm.. i guess it could be from something else... if i include a register.php in index.php, and then in register.php is included the db.php, what path should it have?

Comment: Whatever the path is in your computer. I don't have anyway of knowing that but it should be something like `E:/wamp/inc/db.php`

Comment: hmm, i think i figured it out where is the problem.. register.php and index.php are not in the same folder, so the path is different if i use the short form

Comment: That's what I said at the very beginning of my answer

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507